# A rack fix to lower version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I have to bring a fix that was made on rack 1.4.5 to my 1.36 rack. Can not upgrade rack as ruby is not happy with it

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 3.1.4) ruby depends on
      rack (~> 1.3.6) ruby

```
rack (1.4.5)
```

w/o this fix (https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/rack-1.4/lib/rack/deflater.rb), my app error is randomly throwing app errors.

What is the best way to just bring this change without having to change the version.

Thank you so much for your help!

Jagrati

Comment: But why are you restricted to using such an older version of Rack?

Comment: Ruby does not have a dependency on Rack. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways comes to my mind

either [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833347/how-to-monkey-patch-in-ruby-on-rails)

or

[creating a repo fork from 1.3.6 version patching that and using that repo.](http://www.rubyinside.com/the-end-of-monkeypatching-4570.html)